# Should I use enums or just seperate constants where I'll need their internal values

Tags: c#, enums, constants

Let me use medical doctors to explain my question. Now doctors have different fields of specialization, like Neurologist=0,Oncologist=1,Cardiologist=2,Gynecologist=3 etc. Let's say I have a method that takes one of these specialities as an integer and uses it as a parameter to a stored procedure in a database:

```
DisplaySkills(int speciality)
{
   //create a connection to a database, refer to a stored procedure in the database;
   //send "speciality" as an argument to that stored procedure
}
```

Now, here I'm sort of in a dilemma as to whether I should have those specialities inside an enum or declare them seperately. From the first sight it feels like I should go with enums because it's just the case where "one thing can be one of several" but on the other hand it turns out that if I use enums, then I'll have to cast it to get its internal value. Here's an example:

```
enum Speciality
{
  Neurologist=0,
  Oncologist=1,
  Cardiologist=2,
  Gynecologist=3
}
.............
Speciality spec=Speciality.Oncologist;
.............
DisplaySkills(int(spec));
```

I don't know, maybe having to cast an enum is a perfectly normal practice and is widely used by programmers, but I thought it would impact the performance (no matter noticeably or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with method `DisplaySkills` which accepts enum as parameter. Do casting only when call stored procedure.

Because when is see `DisplaySkills(int speciality)` then there is no connection with specialties declared in some enum. Maybe I should use it this way?

```
DisplaySkills(500);
```

On the other hand:

```
DisplaySkills(Speciality.Neurologist);
```

It tells me about all possible parameter values. Also I'd change name to `DisplaySkillsOf(Speciality.Cardiologist)` - looks more like English sentence then. And I'd added [guard condition](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) to check that passed value contained in `Speciality` enum. Otherwise somebody could do this

```
DisplaySkills((Speciality)500);
```

And only inside this method you convert passed enum to int when creating parameter (looks like you are using ADO.NET)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Speciality", (int)spec));
```

---

One more tip about creating guard for your method. You can use [generic enum wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13248913/470005) to check if appropriate value was passed

```
if (!Enum<Speciality>.IsDefined(spec))
     throw new ArgumentException("spec");
```

Comment: I totally agree both about the leaving potential of passing any integer to the above method and amending the name to be more like English.

Comment: And also, what if want to have constants not as an integral type but as a string? Can enums still be used for this purpose or constants are the only way?

Comment: @MikeJM only integral numeric type could be used as enum values. But you can use name of enum constant later, or write a simple converter

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use enums or just seperate constants where I'll need their internal values

In your case I'll choose `enum` over constant fields.

> maybe having to cast an enum is a perfectly normal practice.

Yes. It is.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use enum instead of say, static constant class, simply because it is `Type safe`.
Rule of a thumb:  if you have just Int + string value, use enum. If you have more fields, use static class.

Comment: What do do you mean by int+string value? Do you mean the name for integral values by string or strings can also be internal values?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about casting then let me tell you it isn't required here you could use this

```
int value = Speciality.Cardiologist.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it's an extra step to do when with constants I can just say Speciality.Cardiologist. So you say it's absolutely ok?